# Keeping a date format when converting to text in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date-format

I am struggling with handling dates within excel/VBA

I have a spreadsheet with a date column, displaying in UK format as expected.

I am then manipulating the spreadsheet and saving it as a text file in order to load the data into another system.

My problem comes when I save the file as it does two things, first due to the US bias of Excel, it attempts to "flip" the dates so for example  1st July 2012 goes from 01/07/2012 to 07/01/2012

Secondly when I then save the file and re-open the text file, it seems to have then dropped the zeros so my date now not only reads the wrong way round, but with no zeros so is showing 7/1/2012

The system I am importing to is very specific about the format of the dates it accepts.

I have tried all sorts

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-1],""dd/mm/yyyy"")"

Cells(x, 3).Value = Left(CStr(Cells(x, 3).Value), 2) + "/" + Mid(CStr(Cells(x, 3).Value), 4, 2) + "/" + Right(CStr(Cells(x, 3).Value), 4)
```

Within Excel both of these do the trick in keeping the format I require, it is when I then save the file as text I get the problems above.

I almost want to pad the date with zeros and force the save as a literal string, but I am running out of ideas.

I am sure this is a simple fix, but I need some other eyes on the problem so any help is appreciated

Comment: How are you "manipulating the spreadsheet and saving it as a text file"? Knowing that would help greatly in figuring out the best way to overcome your problem. Also, the import part of that operation is a different problem. Do you care how the data is stored in the text file or is your only concern that it be imported in the proper format?

Comment: Agree with above. I can't recreate your problem, I just saved a column of UK dates as `.csv` and `.txt` both came out with correct formatting exactly as it was in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi, I literally have two text columns followed by a date column, need to save those as a text file and am doing so in code using 

 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "filename_submit.txt" _
        , FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False

Comment: OK I think I have cracked it !!!!
I added an apostrophe to the cell value and it seemed to do the trick!

Cells(1,1).value = char(39) + Cstr(Cells(1,1).value)

Thanks for all your answers guys, this is the best forum I have found so far for Excel and VBA questions

Rich

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem when saving to .csr file to import into Access. The answer is to add `Local:=True` to the `SaveAs` statement. This keep the dates as UK format.

Below is the code I used:

```
' save data to csv file
ChDir "C:\Documents and Settings\Doug\My Documents\Fitness\LogCard Data"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
 "C:\Documents and Settings\Doug\My Documents\Fitness\LogCard Data\LogCard_access.csv" _
    , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
```